# how to import songs dynamically to our app in Objective C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, media-player, avfoundation

I tried iPhone app.In this app I need to import all songs into table-view when I click on import button.I don't know how to import songs dynamically.Please tell me what are the Frameworks to be used.
But i have played  Locally  saved songs like code:-
using this two Frameworks `AVFoundation.framework,MediaPlayer.framework

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

- (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *filePath = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"drum" ofType:@"mp3"];

    NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSError *error = nil;

    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:fileData
                                                     error:&error];
    [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    self.audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender {
    [self.audioPlayer play];

    UIView *wrapperView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 120, 260, 20)];
    wrapperView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:wrapperView];

    MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: wrapperView.bounds];
    [wrapperView addSubview:volumeView];
}

@end
```

Output  for this code is songs played locally but I need when I click play button it should  import 10 songs in tableView and then songs mush be played.
Please give me any idea.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: from where you are going to import the list of song? from cloud or webservice or from somewhere else.?

Comment: @Adi from my Mobile Please give me any idea.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: ...Yeh got it use this tutorial for your requrement download the code and use it...You will get the list of songs imported in your table list. For now its directly loaded when app launches . You can customise it as per your need . Lets say on button click copy code from view did load and paste in button action method that set...http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-custom-ios-music-player/   Modify this app as per your need

Comment: please try it on device only ..it will crash in  simulator for sure, Do add many songs in ur device and u will see those song in the app imported

Comment: @Adi hoo now i have iPhone but it's not registered for testing.Any other chance.

Comment: connect your device and go to organiser and enable the developer option. your app will run in device